# Implementing a specific action for a model that respond_with(@object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Subscription` model that users can create. Users needs to validate a PIN sent to them to confirm subscription after is created. I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure it out the best way to implement this.

I implemented a `confirms` controller with two `new` and `create` actions.

```
def new
  @confirm = Subscription.new
end

def create
  @keyword = Keyword.joins(:shortcode).where("shortcodes.shortcode = ? and shortcodes.country = ?",params[:subscription][:shortcode],params[:subscription]   [:country]).find_or_create_by_keyword(params[:subscription][:keyword])
  if @confirm = Subscription.where(:phone => params[:subscription][:phone], :country => params[:subscription][:country], :keyword_id => @keyword.id).last
    @confirm.check_subscription_pin(params[:subscription][:pin])
    respond_with(@confirm)
  elsif @confirm && @confirm.errors.any?
    flash[:notice] = @confirm.errors
    render :action => :new      
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Subscription not found."
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

This solution doesn't look very convincing since I would like to always  `respond_with(@confirm)` to allow REST `POST` done via `JSON`.

Answer (score -1):

There's no params[:subscription] received when you make your curl call. Phone and Pin are nested within subscription, hence the error.

```
<pre>undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass</pre>
```

I don't know how to make a curl call with nested params by the way.

Comment: what design suggestion can you propose for this case?

Comment: Try changing your text fields to text_field_tag "phone" instead of f.text_field :phone. So in your controller you get the phone as params[:phone], not params[:subscription][:phone].

But this will mean that you will have to change the creation of the subscrption object manually.