# solving create(params[:subscription]) doing POST with json 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The following query

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/subscriptions.json -d campaign=CAMPAIGN -d phone=6446342542 -d auth_token=QWvHBzkzGCef58osasxz
```

is returning

```
{"errors":{"phone":["can't be blank","Please enter a valid phone number."],"campaign":["can't be blank"]}}
```

The action is

```
def create
  @subscription = Subscription.create(params[:subscription])
  respond_with(@subscription)
end
```

The error seems to be because I'm not sending `params[:subscription]` through json as replied on my previous [Implementing a specific action for a model that respond_with(@object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920275/implemention-a-specific-action-for-a-model-that-respond-withobject/10920387#10920387) question.

If I try to add specifics such as `Subscription.create(params[:subscription][:phone],..)` I get

```
<h1>
 NoMethodError
   in SubscriptionsController#create
```

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -v \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{"subscription":{"campaign":"CAMPAIGN","phone":"6446342542"}, \
"auth_token":"QWvHBzkzGCef58osasxz"}' \
http://localhost:3000/subscriptions.json
```

Try something like that (in one line may be preferrable...without the backslashes...I did that for your reading clarity....but it works with the backslashes too)

Comment: That is not authenticating the `auth_token`.

Comment: How to pass `auth_token` is another story to your question and error that we see. My answer is trying to tell you how you should be passing the `subscription`. I just put `auth_token` there just because I saw you had it in your question. You can try my solution with `-d auth_token=QWvHBzkzGCef58osasxz` and remove it from the `-d '{....}'` that I have put it. Does this authenticate your `auth_token`? **Note**: Usually the auth_tokens are passed using a special http header. You can try: `-H "auth_token: QWvHBzkzGCef58osasxz"` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated answer!